# How do I create a table on vertica that keep the full history of data changes, mainly the update of a row

Tags: vertica

I have to create a table that has primary key, but the name changes like the time and a wish to keep historical of the changes, is that a way to do this on Vertica?

I'm new to vertica, it will be good if you could explains well to me.

Comment: It would help get you answer from SO community if you could post what have you tried, any code samples, where did you get errors. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would search the Internet for "Slowly Changing Dimensions" or SCD. There is no specific way to deal with your request in *any* DBMS I would know. But the techniques around SCD-s are the standard way to answer this need.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure there is no system table that tracks it that specifically, but you can get what you're looking for by querying the `v_monitor.query_requests` and looking for requests that start with `UPDATE`.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM v_monitor.query_requests
WHERE request ILIKE 'UPDATE%';
```

`ILIKE` is a case insensitive `LIKE` statement.

If you want a more precise way of looking for updates, you can execute your updates with a query label: `/*+LABEL('update')*/`

```sql
UPDATE /*+LABEL('update')*/ table
SET col1 = col1 + 1;
```

You can also label your other queries similarly, `INSERT /*+LABEL('insert') INTO table ...`

Then you can query the `query_requests` table searching for those specific labels.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM v_monitor.query_requests
WHERE request_label = 'update';
```

---

Update:

As of 9.2 there is a new system table called `LOG_QUERIES` that keeps track of some DDL changes such as `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `TRUNCATE`, etc. Unfortunately—from my tests—it does not look like it keeps track of updates, so it may not help with your exact question, but it may be useful if you want to keep track of `CREATE` or `ALTER` statements in the future. If you have premium support you could request that they include `UPDATE` statements in this table as well.